# Frenar ejecución ciclo for en lista Python

Tags: python, bucle-for

**Como podria hacer para poder frenar la ejecución de este ciclo for para que pueda ingresar dos input en vez de 3 ? ***---que solo me muestre los nombres Stu y Peter----***  o en todo caso frenar la ejecución del ultimo input para que no me muestre el nombre John**

```
 beatles = []
beatles.append(["John Lennon","Paul McCartney", "George Harrison"])

print(beatles)


for x in range (3):

    Cantante = input("Ingrese el nombre del cantante: ")
    beatles.append(Cantante)

print(beatles)

del beatles[1]
del beatles[2]

print(beatles)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Utiliza slices`print(beatles[:-1])`

Comment: para que sirve el metodo slices?

Comment: No es un método, es la sintaxis, con esto le dices a python como vas a tomar los elementos de un iterable, la sintaxis es`iterable[inicio:fin:paso]`

Comment: me da un error cuando escribo slices, hay que importar alguna libreria?

Comment: Pues nop, no debes de escribir slice ni nada, solo hacer `print(beatles[:-1])`